# 555 Timer Astable Mode

Tags: oscillator, 555, astable

Just to clear things up. This is NOT a homework question, but it is lecture notes used as a practice exam.

I am trying to understand the 555 timer in oscillation (Astable) mode particularly the formula

$$t_l = R_bCln(2) $$ and $$t_h=(R_a + 2R_b)Cln(2) $$

[image]

I have seen the 555 Timer is oscillation where the Discharge port is either floating like this:

[image]

or shorting R_b like so:

EDIT: there should be a capacitor pinned to ground and the DISCH, THRES, TRIG pin in the photo below but I accidentally cut it off.

[image]

So by the formula that describes the time the oscillator is low,
$$R_b = 0 -> t_l=0 $$ which means there should not be any oscillation.

How can this configuration be an oscillator if the Rb resistor is missing?

Photo Cred: EE 409 Cal Poly Prof. Vladmir Prodanov

Comment: I am afraid I do not catch the question or doubt you have. Could you please explain or rephrase your question?

Comment: Shorting the three terminals is nonsense. You might read Electronics Tutorials on 555: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/555_timer.html, for a good explanation.